# Getting bad gateway 502 response from Paypal

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am receiving a paypal 502 bad gateway response when I run my site on my chrome browser.

However, the same request from an incognito window seems to work fine and it also works in firefox on the same machine.

I have cleared my cache so I am concerned that there might be something wrong with the request logic; but my developers cannot reproduce this problem either.  I don't want to find out later that some customers are not able to get the paypal payment screen so I'm hoping to track down the cause of this.

Here's the GET request we make:

```
Request URL:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-57N00510UU258144B&useraction=commit
```

And the request headers:

```
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ectoken=EC-49T82408DT104494D; cookie_check=yes; Apache=10.16.0.11.1431638973833393; upct=40; U4L8zB-ydunrQGaacZ4QhTcWTQO=nlhUU2xhsjSHwYqUWd-TTY_8W2pczcnQ8IMn1-jAtlxnKswogZfSLaZliKxvbaR35sjdx0; VmyeHxjTc5yWtKApgk8-f2SgjEC=XEw7Wsf3s6dovD5b482-er8pyuUZZZzmYOzngmadzSx3vvu5KJDDcUykM3fLeC-IR-Lqtl3KFRACRpIhl7blvnEK1EW; tkkUEuFUb_mahcIlS49RY52hwu8=Cd2Drxd3-HmviU-mUNppGeUftri_7B-NakEP09nDXyD4oeH81HlJJF8G8pmQ-5lefaTzjzdsEC5G8g6VLL7rKgsFdv7P3awp_pMYMG; eightBallUser=false; ppip_signup=; g2bQrGu--VIan06DHlaPDvMaBlO=yx3W0TOYs53uA61kSB81QzzTe_ktz3ucFuAJAylmm92x6jJFnwHGhzkg3aDzgm7cXOKwobYm83pA6gie3qB5Pg8eyq2vKOi9BWZ1Pi_haU5Ji17z-PK-i3RVgj1-2bPVPYYY0C_96LIpgFqzgVcFw_4gPnamJjVZZbSK3po3FujrLQCiN6_BYCbI5ls9bukVtgvYdAR0ueEeN3TVj_dzIIcBxndaO3gWSXJVa_4x7JV91Ieq0aCLh4MT-OcCy4WXCuOMq4WIoDNFS0MqhsWkMWEjoBbb8YKZ1lBdr-bpyPv8k8q7771SsQNeakm6YcllxooQOwrsQdDDF0bLsnYr56hVUXGGq-wj6WaUy1Qncc0axFEdWaTzTzeTZDElLgq5TqoKg0UOKjD5CTRlfo1PllsLOuapYa_Qu2nkkA4F1sLrB4sfDGaWeDY5Gqq1vLcXt6_EJG; 8_5ZXs-cEPcNeubkqPOFshxD0TK=; P6BWWR9LQB-firefly_1=eyJwYXJ0bmVyLXVpIjoidHJ1ZSJ9; Ta7-72v8skl6cLokjOZwUo-Q7wi=; pPJ406xOdkfoXZjvJWuGZTm1_d8=; LANG=en_US; x-pp-s=eyJ0IjoiMTQ2MTAwOTUwMDE3MCIsIm0iOiIwIn0; SPARTAJSESSIONID=69b5a8d755efb; SPARTAJSESSIONIDV2=zrwcayBAF52CfCT8n9Dm.bcQyugW8-7pfYQfYFsPqAhgH-mldcVOX7vDrVHICvhd8y4.BEcacTHGpgm8dLRCIjxfKYDj7hzQgp.yoseFr0gsqIbFTy8KLSknTmXY-9IjX0AJ9CYkzuVv5A-prbq.pqf9x6yiGmuZadB7XPSZcAMir2kgsU.KMxE8DVf6qmwZdSOwiGfL32b1e8vhOAF2Ah12TsRaTDI1id69o7I-BphXl.OFAgwHdg; analytics=IbVDJQAn5MDniiw63TGpWS3Uk8PysW-.b0JQiPeRlstu-DUyGLxaoI-nN4S9KvlerjnnejHzMC4; Tv7XaFXkAfcLyjkmtYddHHs5nwS=d4JWluHkdgoHzHq6FYJFLLVmr_rDej9WQcSAr_CDKP1vdppysAhATYGkfY-6vNmrQWpqhEBcbcofHgIpzN_y4pGqJqmwKeUz94VDxnvbMTypGva1SIQPEgk4ygKgjAeGjmHjkG; -1ILhdyICORs4hS4xTUr41S8iP0=D5NpyTY0HxIVJW2g5yKxP7roL-k_C5N3XxmPrMfuI_L6iS_pExwGTd1-I88DTXaAy7YNDlh26wjb8Soh; jIHSLr4M5Yy4U-3CrkGq73ovwuW=A103.syKD_069OlG6qbaZOEh94tflwhvswKNrp-yr9ZZlJBa7UNspj0EwIXJJmhoLonGk.QAzQhXF_NeKyC1jhsF-RTk-fO9u; id_token=; nsid=s%3Ao0X9PX_Y0MgM6-FRQGOg1LhncXESf7Nk.w2wDfP8JINv2eBKoCtHl1ijRxq4EzmhRVqjINc0SNcw; c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=I6DovXAn2H6HRG2ujtN4t8rojVBc8YLCLfywJYayUyjkGxnxAYSfvk0idSnpAuHxdAFwnn03sJwj1Kx0Hm3Tv-SAPSCzXigaNltq4eJm6ukRtg9oDw1bh1gpbVEZftkFpItym4wystx8LLOgYm4xxUJ1Nb7MUxh8V8r3RwWP6mVUMC7HHuOygIxNynbHQbePbhqKzm4A9nPav8Zj3bry7EOVgqlNZTersB1Q5URfdmKMq_bB9R4uoFBaM6u; i-mmSTyTsv6thyfmaQ1oZIPvE98=o8icCb2LVioho9nw8AAw0WKQ5LOTNV_mzfEaAiY0QP_aS7bj4sevFRccpMKTb91FX1RPvjpckLzscee6sT71E6VluTiwwoRvFAMtnPgSyO77BxwoTb64X7r0Z4-WAdW3qh75EVDcb35jcWSsqSqjDC6E1wA5tpkRG1u_c_8noC7nAGXomKtfjkjocSHeh5BwywRb6N0fulIvLzo_OjEVKt-ziYeAb03lDra-eaSuSVFvK_ncxH0epRUNaACHsglOlG64weE7HDVT-IkDSpyBjiZVMVvyPwWUAgCye3CYxECKJyIXhA0Dsr0w7xW-NlRboLbOcBG5almIpsR2mn1H6WIdlhDPBM2jN_wrEW; pNTcMTtQfrJuaJiwEnWXQ6yNxfq=-cNhrm0-H8ht6beuCftkxgLVbQqQmx3A6fTKD1VpnboSQ7lM-7EGMT0TVqxuDuocrZA3RmiQEMyGQzGzLniKz0AuloYWAmJlm6b1Z4UVWsYdIoMdxWTUgOEsIhSvuyHGFgoJ1E11uJ92w9rfWijw5pL_e6MpFxjTceZR__6qo1ROaRk0K1rKmfaIGKdGj2prtGKeIArZWltCZ3BKu7JDJGtX9j0cs-G4SKWPPurg4J5bA3YZ-OVYeSl4iPpbojGNEn5ovfQdjn7DB3hjg4CyYk5SPc4hG6EcP7NYPh6uksbtb1aJvkftoScHmn2mA_P64wISp75nED4y0KcJqSLfEdcMIEOHjJIZo7uRyyI0V58WVK3YX2DBknhSGl2IqPdCLRUKKJfc_PXmhralyDb2nlUYnbw1OOFMkflZ2k5EUhutN3odVMZQWDXhNCwwX_s2ee42LRk-69OMG8-Y3GPojtkXvaWFdN15qzyV9F4IG_E37ULmUIxVVCdLviylCCWjiJDOSGhCBKJ4wvAd4FIAa67xOmBjd0VhEehZnBVKKLT6VFTATTSB7K6W6Kss5txuQX65dC_QM-zKDL6PLs4iJJF_RWJ14HFEjkEXf6TabTk_S8b7JJ2svk6LvBenfJ3HkjblR6oYjfH0aXR3XJucixMpc06P9Me2ZjnWQ4rYz1SUKL254TwBfS86kVhlbfzSVOc7WHux_tTvsyDOS9hm2iZ3zE0Kb8zOGbLWklvIMY5o8lBL4Ningcfpk6pQ9wDEV64-P5dqMKXQ_yf5Y-ckwEG5AxV5CGFbsTHtobcApZ7paZ6pxjeTXHxd1A1W2Kxug9KrhmMEsRkD5vjjmJhwbGPMpRYIf6THi8aTti9oT55cNCkTX3pFMpkYwCKilLg8iVBLb3hCsx2ZiRsLnsZamUtB-T7OVQ-yg8jPPzwkw7UPJHi73Xp8Eka_3N8_OePC8dIrvBRRYp8xN9VoAQpPMgNJxm71G1xfTrg8E1g1Jkk3eXP6mT21M80WCIq2ZoYKX16ONCtl4sTIMQX6XTa_rxTiBY_haCTYTOghx8qCgLYYIyrHSE0QWpkFfWa4fg7G_UBQT9Nqq58bsMH_N0LAc5nW2GbGtsxi70-8tXGW5xxH0nt-svZDo3u_AAWnfxalP2nhcdY99bd3LVVHa17lSpiEJTd66XbdEj6i805wsSEKbxPCBZmBqo3XZLtahHMZ38-93ZTxUJCzsPJ57hRsu1FwrTd1HJtMuAoBGAcsQNKDdXiaf3-IXzqKMdLM-56hxsg_oCBpqAPjvoxE9iaC5-quJZE2UF4_0sDUsGVcH4Wv2O-00YqnQ7f_npnelCUNKNFxUM0IfspRFqqo177RlTjgcW2Inv5el6SHm8LaKOOXeVDvdHmbeDeoD7eyIznEO4gCBw0HZB_2pXH3dGMKnUSKxbDsbwg9iAjpGyMEKhufpHW1LGDx9NWWwa982n8gKHv6ElcWnTmjBEYYygUdyGCHbvsYHO7g0JDca0OQeyAIK9v2kFbiv-G2TVmpzrL5X95fW8dgPFXQkE0Zfj69Sc29JtrVBL3pfmYjLSs-v-Ap-BjVY5VGTNd4CzyeaePC26zm6H8JWFVyfbaR81x5cCvxnu0; X-PP-K=1464796892:5:NA; Obsh1bpwTE8slCzy4X2PwOLmhre=D103.sjSPDaMrGFiQ-n65Dwshid34rtRaqtf9gJcOeCrMS6A.abbFvvOlZOuQaML8JNEbTleXoke; x-csrf-jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6ImVqLWtFM3RUMTZwaDhrZm1lZ05OSDlSd3JyU0FpYXdrUXoxYkxkLWJxNDBScVBwNVZjRXp3Wlo1T2k2REZGeE9kemxOOElVcExyemtINlVyT1NDRjMtUGp4bnl0YXB2WTctckNRWGhmdHRvdm5MRDR6S3hoU2tiYjBkc3MyMWVDMkY2ZURLdC1kbzBrQzBYejhsWVFfTUpCaTZadHVCMmdsNi0zZDBGYmpHeDBWYWktMjBuc3JYaTJCd3FsVGZkSnhjd2NVYVgwLTdXRmlUNzJQT3ozcTRMYUdzMCIsImlhdCI6MTQ2NDk3NzA3MCwiZXhwIjoxNDY0OTgwNjcwfQ.LnhIARq1QfGBvbBZacz0XhDlzYW84sWGjVpyUkmTrmk; AKDC=slc-b-origin-www-2.paypal.com; _gat=1; login_email=jason%40ucodemy.com; fn_dt=72960c2e3a054c13ba2c9bf236cf6bfa; KHcl0EuY7AKSMgfvHl7J5E7hPtK=Zv_aLJcUP8xF5AiqUTnrPOGq9LEyN_2CPF6JCQ80Q9xYiYSULMcPntn5H3k1YCG6K1QinVUf-seLv7Fe; ui_experience=login_type%3DEMAIL_PASSWORD%26home%3D3; DPz73K5mY4nlBaZpzRkjI3ZzAY3QMmrP=; AV894Kt2TSumQQrJwe-8mzmyREO=; X-PP-ADS=AToBjZEGV9EhlnBNNaTZvTV9FBvpYsY7AUBpKleCljtAOuPArRmEqd36WjBmOwE1UlNXQNLdelRDZjFYNL4Bd6Vq8w; SEGM=bRdV1vB0ebq9RKdAb3xSHowCi6QnnlCiDOLNk8i1mAuLl1vTbzHQwWajSsMe8mvoWiJtY1GnpzN4Y-sixGy7BQ; h3AkkNwOxPEPRslUIy3vhqkniPK=1MQj6iPRAu5-vhgNV0zkoRDIAAoSUqOCQ9fjKXzaQ3C_VKRUD5b7X5I58pK; VHzDQylDGxsX9ZzQOaL5x-ItYUu=dOgBqGUh_R8IWhaK2OL8pPfftLiRshO0hwpATEcafqNbEbb4rWdY357uWn_lRNKJhlhtibp79apsAiGbw9sx2EoAn80; cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=6xj4lSfVCNifZzOknGKaz3vFMyvnGIftrBaWUAvSJrPlRrB3BjBtpgfbowD7rIqP_xxdd0vFkAK4PQwfXAebc07PenJ5sQWE6sgP4gwLwj4x3IIPm2xVjGNoTISZBznLJ38CAzhOnQGpPHZSbW1nIIOrTEEwYA9c-OxORUz2KB_ekSa7B7gHsBRtlwv761uMlvivYcXalfyYDQAC80UGSf6X1pgW4AHA5xZb4KdJQo0VQtr7Nmb_d39LqKMxUiiA6D56h8G_PBDDtTl-qC3_ZgG50EYJI72rRFaxf0Rdx_280DGwoFqCJWegT2Cl3wYpAraDsLD6mFZD-39CINVPI6E9T1x7n_U8wSvXD8odh4xBgXudLa3b45SWAb3j8zydHVaBJiQgPCDb2wlpp47MSe0bcaCCvqZw37QLUKXEK0M81n6qNgAECNaV-08; navlns=0.4.0; feel_cookie=a%2015%20_complaint-view%20b%2019%20_choose-transaction%20c%206%20webscr%20d%206%20webscr%20e%2051%20CaseManagement%2fcustomerservice%2fResolutionCenter.xsl%20f%2031%20History%2faccount%2fTransaction.xsl%20g%205%20en_US%20h%205%20en_US%20i%2051%20xpt%2fCaseManagement%2fcustomerservice%2fResolutionCenter%20j%2031%20xpt%2fHistory%2faccount%2fTransaction%20k%2026%20Resolution%20Center%20-%20PayPal%20l%2029%20Select%20a%20transaction%20-%20PayPal%20; s_pers=%20s_ev32%3D%255B%255B%252713680%25257C225003%25257CUNSUB%25257CPNP%2527%252C%25271435686403381%2527%255D%255D%7C1593539203380%3B%20s_fid%3D05AF6EADAEA33311-0237336D5D25A434%7C1528150385627%3B%20gpv_c43%3Dresolutioncenter%253Alanding%7C1465080185633%3B%20gpv_events%3Dno%2520value%7C1465080185637%3B; s_sess=%20v0%3D13680%257C225003%257CUNSUB%257CPNP%3B%20c_m%3DOther%2520Natural%2520Referrersundefinedwww.google.com%3B%20lt%3D%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20tr_p1%3Dresolutioncenter%253Alanding%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B%20v31%3DResolutionCenter%253ALanding%3B%20s_ppv%3D100%3B; navcmd=_login-done; consumer_display=USER_HOMEPAGE%3d3%26USER_TARGETPAGE%3d0%26USER_FILTER_CHOICE%3d0%26BALANCE_MODULE_STATE%3d1%26GIFT_BALANCE_MODULE_STATE%3d1%26LAST_SELECTED_ALIAS_ID%3d0%26RM_NAV%3d2%26SELLING_GROUP%3d1%26PAYMENT_AND_RISK_GROUP%3d1%26SHIPPING_GROUP%3d1%26MCE2_ELIGIBILITY%3d3; cookie_nav_is_vt_enabled=; cookie_nav_is_uum_enabled=; x-pp-p=xh4LPiqR3nDDhTURZZaNKtyLPzzs8shTH5oMBxG30OLJ5U3YN0ylPRShyLZVHMLLga3Io.uZnsPWbrDMmIc.HBNqM9ZCbcsD.p6y4pueAnxzGGglSKENHv6y4bllKw95FT6CxYXKM0QHlCkCsXO8g0PXOHd-9RTCKH1lfjZqkWAY-XCoXPAOyF9RN2twreyFLiQGB2VheeN0loxCQ1khMfdenPgZiqozHzGhCWnFUlO31PCWNhujR2ODJ4cW8xYE; LANG=en_US%3BUS; tsrce=bizexpnodeweb; X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE6.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dbizexpnodeweb%26TIME%3D894653271%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dslcb.slc; ts=vreXpYrS%3D1559749360%26vteXpYrS%3D1465080383%26vr%3D5455203914d0a4a067b7727afe2414a8%26vt%3D1d7911c91550a4a59583eb93fcff3d6f; HaC80bwXscjqZ7KM6VOxULOB534=qwIGnYdm3pN_hU9H6g6DtihSLf6l2KDLHKXoKgueabn-KE6OGAfa5JuhgmQlncNh4m66nk4slq6NcYEXnv9ek__vMAzNw876rR2_NIWmVH1_oWUF_Jf6dL7UbSzQowNNEPDu4m; _ga=GA1.2.774544044.1431638976
Host:www.paypal.com
Referer:https://www.itchcode.com/create.html
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Same exact issue for me. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: Same here. Works fine from Chrome Incognito and other browsers, but not Chrome ... I tried to restart Chrome, and empty all cookies, but it didn't help.

Comment: Same problem for me - although when I cleared cookies completely (all cookies for ever) that made it work again. I can only imagine in my case it's either due to an existing login on the paypal business account or something left over from being logged in to developer.paypal.com or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I had and fix this issue.

Previously I accepted an untrusted certificate for my website on chrome. Then I change my certificate to a good one but chrome keep old certificate information.

When I do a payment test, paypal front redirect to a backurl that is not trusted to your chrome => the 502 error pop.

Solution is to refresh your certificate in your chrome.